# What happens with $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\ln(p_n!)}{\psi(p_n)}\right)_n$?

Tags: number-theory

What happens with the sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{\ln(p_n!)}{\psi(p_n)}\right)_n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime, $x!$ is factorial and $\psi(x)$ second Chebyshev function? Does it $\to \infty$ or $\to C$?

Comment: Note that $p_n$ can be replaced by any sequence of naturals tending to $\infty$; primality is irrelevant.

Comment: What an odd question.  Don't you mean $\ln n!$ or some other variation that makes the two ratio balanced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Stirling's formula

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x!}{x \ln x} = 1
$$

and by the prime number theorem

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\psi(x)}{x} = 1
$$

so

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln p_n!}{\psi(p_n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_n \ln p_n}{p_n} = \infty.
$$

Comment: So, if the question was $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln p_n!}{\ln p_n\psi(p_n)}$? It would be $= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_n \ln p_n}{p_n\ln p_n} = 1$?

Comment: Am I reading the denominator correctly as $\psi(p_n)\ln p_n$?  If so, then yes.